# Scanning User Input for Strings Declared in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am creating a program that scans user input for words that are listed in an array. The `find()` function seems like it'll work, but I can't find anything showing how to implement it for what I want to do. I'm pretty new to programming (obviously).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string subj [5]={"I","He","She","We","They"};
string verb [5]={" like"," hate"," sacrifice"," smell"," eat"};
string obj [5]={" bacon","s cats","s bagels","s children","s cops"};
string greeting [5]={"How are you","How's it going","Sup dude","Hey","Hello"};
string negvibe [4]={"bad","terrible","lousy","meh"};

string userfeeling;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int rando = rand() %5;//generates a random number between 0 and 4
    int rando1 = rand() %5;
    int rando2 = rand() %5;

    cout << greeting [rando1] << "." << endl;
    getline(std::cin,userfeeling);

    if .... // What has to be done here?
         find(negvibe, negvibe + 4, userfeeling) != negvibe + 4);
    // Something like that?

    // then ...
    {
        cout << subj[rando] << verb[rando1] << obj[rando2] <<"." <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code with in the if statement.  Also what are you trying to do with 

find(negvibe, negvibe + 4, userfeeling) !=negvibe + 4);   Is that suppose to be part of the if statement or is it supposed to do something else?

Comment: Wow that was fast. Sorry. That is the whole of the if statement. I pulled find() from this discussion.                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236431/c-how-can-i-compare-a-user-input-to-a-list-of-string-with-strict-ordering                                                            
I am trying to get the program to scan the user input from    getline(std::cin,userfeeling); to see if the user input contains any words that are strings inside of the array, string negvibe[] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `find` function will find some element of the `negvibe` array that is equal to `userfeeling`.  If you are checking whether any element of `negvibe` is a substring of `userfeeling`, you should loop through `negvibe` and use the `std::string::find` method.

```
bool found_negvibe = false;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(negvibe) / sizeof(*negvibe); i++) {
    found_negvibe = found_negvibe || userfeeling.find(negvibe[i]) != string::npos;
}
```

Also, you don't need to specify the size of the `negvibe` array, you can write this:

```
string negvibe[] = {"bad","terrible","lousy","meh"};
```

One more thing, you might prefer to use a `std::vector` over an array, if only because c++'s faculties for getting the size of a vector are slightly more succinct than those for getting the size of an array.

```
vector negvibe = {"bad","terrible","lousy","meh"};

bool found_negvibe = false;
for (int i = 0; i < negvibe.size(); i++) {
    found_negvibe = found_negvibe || userfeeling.find(negvibe[i]) != string::npos;
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To make find work properly you should user iterators like so

```
if(find(std::begin(negvibe), std::end(negvibe), userfeeling) != std::end(negvibe)){
  //code you want to happen if your word is found
}
```

Also in your current code, the if statement doesnt actually do anything since you end it with a semicolon and not {} or leave it blank if its one line.  You can see an example of the if statement as well

Below is a link to find and iterators
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: `negvibe` is a c-style array so it doesn't have begin() and end() member functions. You probably meant to type `std::begin(negvibe)` and `std::end(negvibe)`. And you spelt begin wrong. Fix those and it'll be a good answer.